# Active class on navbar isn't working jekyll

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I'm having difficulty getting the .active class to work on my site. It's hard to show through jsfiddle but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/10/) it is. Here's a picture of what I'm looking at. I'm not sure what element in the HTML I should be targetting to make it active since I have all this Liquid in here.

You can see I'm on index.html and it's not making the "Hhome" button black.
[image]

This are the different variations that I tried but didn't work. I'm not sure how to make this work with jekyll since it's assigning the class "active" when I serve it...

```
#navbar ul .active a
#navbar ul.active a
#navbar ul li a
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS rule should work:

```
#navbar ul .active > a {color: red;}
```

Can we see the actual website?

Comment: This is just on my own VM so nothing's online yet. Here's the default.html though, I threw it into the js portion of jsfiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/11/